# What does foo change into if used in a function as an argument that can not be changed anymore?

Tags: javascript, function

What exactly have I attached as an argument to function #1? A new object, a string, something else? It does not look like a reference, because changing foo has no effect. From what I can see, bar1, bar2 and bar 3 behave exactly the same. Is there a difference between any of them?

```
foo = 5;

bar1 = (function(){return fooBar(foo);}()); // <--- #1
bar2 = (function(){return fooBar("5");}()); // <--- #2
bar3 = (function(){return fooBar(5);}());   // <--- #3

alert(bar1);
alert(bar2);
alert(bar3);
```

edit -> as requested, the fooBar function

```
var p = 3;

function fooBar(n)
{
    return (p*n);
}

foo = 5;
bar = (function(){return fooBar(foo);}());

alert(bar);
```

edit 2

```
function fooBar(n)
{
    return (n[0]+n[1]);
}

foo = [20, 15];
bar = (function(){return fooBar(foo);}());

foo = [4, 565];

alert(bar); // 35
```

Comment: Please provide the `fooBar()` function.

Comment: I've attached the fooBar function, but it's not something complicated yet. I'm trying things out. What can I do, what not. I wasn't expecting this to work.

Comment: foo does not change into anything. Why would it? You are just referencing it at that moment in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar1` becomes the result that is returned from `fooBar(foo)` which is `fooBar(5)` and evaluates to `3*5`, finally `15`

And because these 3 statements are written as self-invoking functions `function(){ .... }()`, changing foo after that `bar1 = ...` statement will have no effect, since the value of `foo` has already been passed into it.

Comment: ok, so it takes a snapshot of foo and stores it somewhere? Is it valid JavaScript?

Comment: It's valid, but not easy to read by any means. 
Basically, primitive values like `int`, `string`, etc. are *passed-by-value*. On the other hand, the type `array` and `object` (which include `function`) are *passed-by-reference*.

Comment: Could you take a look at edit 2? I've used an array and the effect is the same as with the primitive values.

Comment: `bar` gets evaluated first and receives the value `35`, that's correct. Changing `foo` after that point won't have any impact on the value of `bar`.

Comment: you're right. Neither does changing p in the first edit. I must have missed something. The function is nothing more than a number. For a moment I thought I got what I was looking for.

Comment: What else were you looking for? Did you want bar to be a function that remembered the original foo value?

Comment: yes, the foo should be fixed, but the function should reevaluate. I can do that, but it requires bar() and I was trying to get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `foo` variable is global (defined without the `var` keyword / defined in an outer scope) it is available inside your anonymous function as well.

Your `fooBar` function is however undefined so hard to tell what it's doing.

Also, it's better to use `console.dir()` to dump variables as it also shows the type.

Edit: Apparently `console.dir()` does not show the type (in Chrome at least)

Comment: ok, but I can change foo and bar remains the same function, like it has been turned into a constant or a string, so it is not foo that is passed.